# Additional field to enum members in Python

Tags: python, enums, ienumerable, enumeration, enumerate

I would like to use enum mechanism properly on Python side. [There](https://github.com/5monkeys/django-enumfield) is a fantastic example for django because the text feature of enum items can be changed without touching enum mechanism. However, I am looking for an example in Python side. I am aware of [this support for enumerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) and [this post](https://rednafi.github.io/reflections/add-additional-attributes-to-enum-members-in-python.html) in order to add additional attributes to enum members. However, I have no success so far on my side.

Basically, I would like to be able to iterate through enum and also call any item from three (CAT, 1, "cat") interchangeably like in two C arrays with enum. How can I access from each of them (CAT, 1, "cat") to each of them properly in Python? What is the best pythonic way ?

```
from enum import Enum, unique
class Animals(Enum):
    CAT     = 1, "Cat"
    DOG     = 2, "Dog"
    SHARK   = 3, "custom shark name"

    @classmethod
    def value(cls, value):
        for k, v in cls.__members__.items():
            if k == value:
                return v
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"'{cls.__name__}' enum not found for '{value}'")

print(Animals.value('Dog')) #must return 2
print(Animals.xyz(2)) #must return 'Dog'
print(Animals.DOG.name) #must return 'Dog'
print(Animals.DOG.value) #must return 2
...etc...
```

Note: I do NOT want to separate them into two enum classes like first one contains custom names the other class contains index. Both index and its custom name must be in the same line to manage items suitably.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Your first two `print()`s are invalid -- `Enum` does not work like that.

To get something similar to what you want:

```
from enum import Enum, unique
class Animals(Enum):
    #
    CAT     = 1, "Cat"
    DOG     = 2, "Dog"
    SHARK   = 3, "custom shark name"
    #
    def __new__(cls, value, label):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = value
        member.label = label
        return member
    #
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        # if we get here, simple value lookup has already failed
        for k, v in cls.__members__.items():
            if value in (k, v.label):
                return v

print(Animals.DOG.value)  # was Animals.value('Dog'))
print(Animals(2).label)   # was Animals.xyz(2))
print(Animals.DOG.label)
print(Animals.DOG.value)
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can we access from label to its value in this structure as it was on my first print ? Like: from 'Dog' to 2 or from 'Dog' to DOG.